# Installation of express in node js

Tags: node.js, express, installation

Sir, I am unable to install express in node js using command prompt.

npm install express

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why you are trying to install express inside your node setup in c drive ?

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343606/installation-of-express-in-node-js/41343772#41343772) below help you? Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with permissions. You have to run as admin if you want to install in that path (Program Files). But you probably don't want to install Express there, but in your application's directory.

Also, there are errors with non existing package.json which you can create running:

```
npm init
```

because if you want to install with saving into package.json then you will have to have the package.json first.

Enter your application directory and if there is a package.json run:

```
npm install express --save
```

If there is no package.json then run this first:

```
npm init
```

and then:

```
npm install express --save
```

Make sure that you have write permissions in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run **npm install** in your Program Files directory. Instead run it a) in a project directory in c:\users\NAME... or b) globally with **npm install -g**.

I would start with the following steps

1) Create a **new folder** for your project in your file system somewhere under *C:\users\NAME...*

```
mkdir PROJECT_NAME
cd PROJECT_NAME
```

2) In this folder, run **npm init** to create a new **package.json** for your project. Follow the wizard in CMD (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)

```
npm init
```

3) Then you can install all the packages you need with **npm install** (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

```
npm install --save PACKAGE_NAME
```

- Note that npm creates a **node_modules/** folder where it stores the packages
- With the **--save** argument, npm adds a reference to the package in your **package.json** file

As @rsp stated already, to perform npm install in *C:\Program Files*, you would need higher privileges. Running npm as administrator is quit a bad practice.